# How difficult and what should I Google to create an App that allows one person to transfer a NFT to another person?

Tags: security, nft

If I wanted to create a super simple app that would allow one person to transfer an NFT to another person, what things should I consider/Google and how difficult would that be?  Obviously the biggest fear is hacking so just I need to make sure that the NFT actually gets exchange properly.

I'm not sure what I should Google or what terms I should search for?  Would using Google cloud as my server be safe enough?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to program a wallet?

Comment: I'm so new to this, I'm not even sure what to Google for.  Whatever is the simplest and safest is all I need.  Just very simple mechanism to transfer a NFT to another person.

Comment: What NFT do you want to transfer? Where did you buy the NFT?

Comment: Actually no, i don't want to program a wallet.  I am just trying to learn the tech.  Let's say I create an NFT and I want to give it to a friend, is there a easy way to do it securely?  I guess he can use any wallet he chooses and I can use any wallet I choose.

Comment: There are platforms that allow creation of NFT without programming: OpenSea, Rarible, Foundation, and several others.